# How to apply Toon Shader into texture material

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, shader-nodes, toon-shading

I have watched a YouTube video about Toon Shader that use diffuse and Coloramp node to manipulate color and sharpness of the object's shadow:
[image]

Then I have a penguin model with texture painted in Substance painter:
[image]

Question: How do I apply the Diffuse and ColorRamp node into the Penguin's material so I can manipulate color and sharpness of the Penguin'shadow, but also keep the base material as before

YouTube video of the Toon Shader: https://youtu.be/yjJWEsjR79Q

Comment: So you want to preserve the PBR qualities of the material (normal, roughness, etc...) but just be able to better control a "toonish" shadow cutoff?

Comment: Yes sir, that's exactly what I want

Comment: There are a few ways to accomplish something like that, each with different end results - I guess the best question is do you want the end result to look "toony", or do you just want better (somewhat realistic) control over the shadow?

Answer (score 3):

Since there are a few ways to do this, with somewhat wildly varying results, I'll just start with this example and see how well it goes.

Because you are using an *Image Texture* for your BaseColor, what you want to do is capture the shadows from a Diffuse BSDF (clamped with a ColorRamp), and then multiply those "shadow" values over your original BaseColor. For added detail, you can connect the Roughness, and Normal (or any combo of the 3) from the appropriate image textures (or Normal Map node for the Normal) to the Diffuse BSDF as well (not shown here):

[image: SHadowz]